# Is there a way to show District using Places autosuggest entry point?

Tags: here-api

Im using the places v1 autosuggest entry point, with the following request

https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&q=550+5e+avenue&at=45.44569010000001%2C-73.66412120000001&size=5&result_types=address%2Cplace&addressFilter=countryCode%3Dca

So basically Im searching within Canada for places and address. The address Im looking for is in Montreal however there are two districts with that address, Verdun, and Lachine, however in the response there is no way to differentiate them without visiting the href to go to the full places details. Is there a way to display the district so its possible to differentiate the results?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the endpoint of 'autosuggest' does not support this district field.
However the 'search' endpoint shows the district. YOu an use this one instead.

See: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/media-type-search.html